# Select Category as Page Parent

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I've got a custom post type called Products and when i go to select page parent i only get other pages of the same post type.

Is it possible to select a category as a parent for the page?

The reason i'm asking is i have a plugin that lets me automatically add child pages to a menu under the parent. If i can somehow be able to set a category as a parent to the custom post type it should automatically add it to the menu.

Here's the plugin i'm using.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-descendants-as-submenu-items/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't need to set a category as a page parent, i found this which did exactly what i needed. It shows a menu of categories and subcategories as well as their posts.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/collapsing-categories/

Comment: ...then your question was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can only select other pages as page parents.

If you wish to have a page as the child under the category menu item, you should create the top-level menu item in the Menu editor, then manually add a menu item for the page in question to the newly-created category menu item.

Comment: Thanks. That's what i wanted to avoid, i'm trying to get it to add to the menu automatically so you don't have to add it to the menu every single time a product is added. Is it possible to select a parent that is a different post type?

Comment: In general, no, it's not possible.

Comment: in general? I really need a way to add products to the menu automatically or at least without having to go into the menu every time i create a new one. I've found this plugin which i think does what i need (not sure though) but haven't a clue how to use it or indeed if it is what i need. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Comment: I say in general only because nothing is truly impossible with enough hacking, but it's not within the scope of Wordpress.  I am not familiar enough with the posts-to-posts plugin to truly say if it's what you need, but at first blush, it does not appear to be what you require. I believe your only option that doesn't require lots of extra coding would be to manually place your page(s) beneath the category menu item in the Menu Editor.

Comment: I also found this plugin which seems to do exactly as i want. I menu of category and their posts. However it has been updated for some time so it doesn't work. I don't know if it's because theirs some incompatibility with wordpress for it's just conflicting with Jquery. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/superslider-menu/